# Recommended resources for viewshed generation using Grass GIS 7.4

Tags: grass-gis, virtual-machine, grass-7.4

I am working on a project where I need to create viewshed areas around towers with a radius of 5000 meters.
The underlying DEM I created using free Lidar data.
Uptill now I did all this on a laptop with a core i7 proc and 8GBs of RAM. Pretty powerful but does not seem to be enough to complete the task within a reasonable timeframe.

Therefore I am considering the setup of a couple of virtual machines on AWS and I need input on what you guys out there would recommend in terms of resources: CPU, amount of RAM etc.

The process is the following:

1. Merge DEM tiles into one huge TIFF that fully contains the DEM within 5000 m of the tower.
2. Use this DEM (in TIFF) format in Grass 7.4 (r.viewshed) to generate the viewshed area.
3. Vectorize the result viewshed raster and delete areas that have a DN value of 0 (not visible)

Even a smaller subset (a sector of 10°-20° from north) took half of the night to produce only the viewshed so I am kind of desperate to speed things up no matter what.

Comment: What resolution is your DEM? How many Towers?

Comment: Say a dozen towers are located in my immediate area of interest. Pixel width and height are both 0.0000013 arc degrees Ideally if I could speed things up for one tower that would already be progress.

Comment: 0.15 meters to be more exact.

Comment: I would use the DEM to model RF propagation and how buildings and vegetation obstruct signal.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Lets suppose I had already resampled the DEM, do you have any recommendations as to what amount of RAM and processing power I 'll need for a smooth(er) run. I am aware that the more the better, but want to be reasonable at the same time. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: 5E8 cells (per tower) doesn't seem that large and should fit in 8 GB. You can speed it up by running them in parallel.

Comment: Let me recommend to not use a degree based spatial reference system but to reproject the data to a metric projection.

Comment: r.viewshed with --verbose flag gives you an estimate of required memory. Also I would recommend for each r.viewshed computation limit first the computational region based on the position of the tower and max distance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Anna! I have not yet run r.viewshed with the verbose flag, but will try it with future calculations. Also, I have limited the computational region already which was a huge help.